# Replace Excel Link/Relationships between other files

Tags: excel, powershell

I work on a Powershell Script to Replace Links/Relationships in an .xlsx File.
I figured out that the external Links are stored there: xl\externalLinks_rels\externalLink1.xml.rels

Everyting in my Script works fine the old Links are replaced with the new ones in the .xml.rels file but when i open the "updated" Excel File the old Links are still there. The .xlsx File is already a .zip file i have to work on this but that should not be a problem

Thanks for your Help!

`

```
# Path to Source 
$sourceFilePath = "C:\Users\myPath"

# Temporary WorkFolder
$tempFolder = "C:\Temp\XLSXUnzip"

# Unzip Source .zip/.xlsx 
$archiveExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($sourceFilePath)
if ($archiveExtension -ne ".zip") {
    Write-Host "Die Quelldatei muss im .zip-Archivformat vorliegen."
    exit
}

Expand-Archive -Path $sourceFilePath -DestinationPath $tempFolder -Force

# Path to .xml that contains external Links
$xmlFilePath = Join-Path -Path $tempFolder -ChildPath "xl\externalLinks\_rels\externalLink1.xml.rels"

# old Link Pattern
$oldLinkPattern = 'file:///C:\Users\myPath'

# Neues Verlinkungsziel
$newLinkTarget = 'file:\\\new Path'

# Check if .xml is there
if (Test-Path -Path $xmlFilePath) {
    try {
        # Lade die XML-Datei
        $xmlDoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
        $xmlDoc.Load($xmlFilePath)

        $namespaceManager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xmlDoc.NameTable)
        $namespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships")

        # Find Element old Relationship
        $relationshipElement = $xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:Relationship[@Target='$oldLinkPattern']", $namespaceManager)

        if ($relationshipElement -ne $null) {
            # Replace Relationship
            $relationshipElement.SetAttribute("Target", $newLinkTarget)
            $xmlDoc.Save($xmlFilePath)

            Write-Host "Externer Verlinkung wurde ersetzt."
        } else {
            Write-Host "Keine passende Verlinkung gefunden."
        }

    } catch {
        Write-Host "Fehler beim Bearbeiten der XML-Datei: $_"
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "Die XML-Datei wurde nicht gefunden."
}

# create new .zip-file and rename in .xlsx
$newZipFilePath = "C:\Users\mypath"
Compress-Archive -Path $tempFolder\* -DestinationPath $newZipFilePath -Force

$newXLSXFilePath = $newZipFilePath -replace '\.zip$', '.xlsx'
Rename-Item -Path $newZipFilePath -NewName $newXLSXFilePath

Write-Host "Neue XLSX-Datei wurde erstellt."

# delete work Folder
Remove-Item -Path $tempFolder -Force -Recurse

Write-Host "Aktualisierte XLSX-Datei wurde erstellt und in XLSX-Format umgewandelt."
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context on the links themselves you're trying to update ? Are we talking about cells in your excel sheets that have links ? If that's teh case, I'd suggest you to have a look at this powershell module as modifying the xml you're mentioning might not necessarily be the only option to do that [link](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) try this

Comment: Yeah Sure. For Example: We are working in Worksheet 1. On Worksheet 1 in Cell A1 you have the Value "1". Now we copy Value "1" and paste it as a Link on Worksheet 2 in Cell A2. In the Cell on Worksheet 2 you just see the Value "1", but if you select Cell A2 you can see the Full Path. If you change the Value in Worksheet 1 it automatically changes in Worksheet 2.
Because of an Server Change, we have to change all the Paths. The Import-Excel cmdlet can not provide the function I need (i guess).